# Java guessing game issues

Tags: java

I'm supposed to be create a program that prompts the user to enter a integer as the highest value for the secret along with a number of guesses for them. The program generates a secret number. After they exhaust all their guesses or guess correctly my program should ask the user whether they want to play again or not. Currently I'm have issues with the if statement for determining whether someone answered correctly and then ask if they would like to see the secret number. Currently when I do so whether I guesses correctly or not it still causes the secret number to ask whether the user wants it to be shown. I don't know what to do. Also at the end of the while loop, near the end of the program I want to ask the user after the second round whether they would like to play again. But it is ignored for some reason along with setting the next boolean input false to the TrueOrFalse boolean below. If anyone could give suggestions on how to shorten the code that would be great! Sorry for all the questions, I'm just really stuck. Thank you if you could help.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      
       Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
       
     System.out.println("Hello! Here are the rules for this game:");
     
     System.out.println("1. You choose the limit of the secret number!");
     
     System.out.println("2. I generate the secret number!");
      
     System.out.println("3. You choose the maximum number of guesses!");
     
     System.out.println("4. You try to guess the secret number I generated within the number of guesses you entered!"); 
     
     System.out.println("5. You may win a prize!"); 
     
     System.out.println("With that being said, would you like to play? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false."); 
     
     boolean wantToPlay = input.nextBoolean();
     
      while (wantToPlay != true)
    {
     System.out.println ( "Thank you and remember to wash your hands! You may close me.");  
       
           System.out.println ( "Did you accidentally press false? If yes please enter true, if not you may leave the program. ");
      
      wantToPlay = input.nextBoolean();
      
    }
      
    System.out.println ( "Please enter the limit of the secret number.");
    
    System.out.println("Please note that your secret number will be between zero and the number you just entered."); 
    
    int upperLimit = input.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println  ( "The upper bound you entered is" + " " + upperLimit + "." + " " + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false.");
      
    boolean trueOrFalse = input.nextBoolean();
      
    while (trueOrFalse != true | upperLimit == 0)
    {
         System.out.println ( "Please enter the new upper bound of the secret number. If you answered true before that is because you cannot enter 0 as a upper limit.");  

      upperLimit = input.nextInt();
       
           System.out.println ( "The upper bound you entered is" + " " + upperLimit + "." + " " + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false. ");
      
      trueOrFalse = input.nextBoolean();
      
    }
     int secretNumber = (int) (Math.random()*upperLimit);
    
      
    System.out.println ( "Please enter the maximum number of guesses you would like.");
    
    int numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();
    
     if (numberOfGuesses >= (secretNumber+1) || numberOfGuesses == 0)
    {
    System.out.println ("Please note that the number of guesses you entered is equal or greater than the possible number of values for the secret number.");
    
    System.out.println ("If you would like more of a challenge please re-enter the number of guesses below." );
    }
    
    System.out.println  ( "The number of guesses you entered is" + " " + numberOfGuesses + "." + " " + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false.");
      
    boolean guess = input.nextBoolean();
    
    while (guess != true)
    {
     System.out.println ( "Please enter the new maximum number of guesses for the secret number.");  
      
      numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();
      
        if (numberOfGuesses >= (secretNumber+1) || numberOfGuesses == 0)
    {
    System.out.println ("Please note that the number of guesses you entered is equal or greater than the possible number of values for the secret number.");
    
    System.out.println ("If you would like more of a challenge please re-enter the number of guesses below. If you entered zero please re-enter the number of guesses." );
    }
       
     System.out.println ( "The number of guesses you entered is" + " " + numberOfGuesses + "." + " " + "Is that correct. If yes please enter true, if not please enter false. ");
      
      guess = input.nextBoolean();
      
    }
  
  boolean loop = false;
  
    for (int i= 0; i < numberOfGuesses; ++i)
    {
    System.out.println ("Please enter your guess.");
   
    int guesses = input.nextInt();
    
        if (guesses > secretNumber)
        {
         System.out.println ("Your guess too high.");
        }
        
    if (guesses < secretNumber)
        {
         System.out.println ("Your guess too low.");
         
         loop = false;
         
        }

       if (guesses == secretNumber) 
       { 
        System.out.println ("Congragulations you won the game.");
        
         loop = true;
        
        break;
       }
           
    }
    
    if (loop = false)
    
    System.out.println ("Sorry you lost the game.");
    
    System.out.println ("Would you like to see the secret number? If so please enter true, if not please enter false");
    
    boolean seeSecretNumber = input.nextBoolean();
    
    if (seeSecretNumber == true)
    {
    System.out.println ("The secret number was "+ secretNumber);
    
    }
    
    System.out.println ("Would you like to play again? If so please enter true, if not please enter false.");
    
    boolean playAgain = input.nextBoolean();
      
     while (playAgain == true)
    {
      System.out.println ( "Please enter the limit of the secret number.");
    
    System.out.println("Please note that your secret number will be between zero and the number you just entered."); 
    
     upperLimit = input.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println  ( "The upper bound you entered is" + " " + upperLimit + "." + " " + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false.");
      
     trueOrFalse = input.nextBoolean();
      
    while (trueOrFalse != true | upperLimit == 0)
    {
     System.out.println ( "Please enter the new upper bound of the secret number. If you answered true before that is because you cannot enter 0 as a upper limit.");  
      
      upperLimit = input.nextInt();
       
           System.out.println ( "The upper bound you entered is" + " " + upperLimit + "." + " " + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false. ");
      
      trueOrFalse = input.nextBoolean();
      
    }
     secretNumber = (int) (Math.random()*upperLimit);
    
      
    System.out.println ( "Please enter the maximum number of guesses you would like.");
    
    numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();
    
    if (numberOfGuesses >= (secretNumber+1) || numberOfGuesses == 0)
    {
    System.out.println ("Please note that the number of guesses you entered is equal or greater than the possible number of values for the secret number.");
    
    System.out.println ("If you would like more of a challenge please re-enter the number of guesses below." );
    }
    
    System.out.println  ( "The number of guesses you entered is" + " " + numberOfGuesses + "." + " " + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false.");
      
    guess = input.nextBoolean();
    
    while (guess != true)
    {
     System.out.println ( "Please enter the new maximum number of guesses for the secret number.");  
      
      numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();
      
        if (numberOfGuesses >= (secretNumber+1) || numberOfGuesses == 0)
    {
    System.out.println ("Please note that the number of guesses you entered is equal or greater than the possible number of values for the secret number.");
    
    System.out.println ("If you would like more of a challenge please re-enter the number of guesses below. If you entered zero please re-enter the number of guesses." );
    }
       
     System.out.println ( "The number of guesses you entered is" + " " + numberOfGuesses + "." + " " + "Is that correct. If yes please enter true, if not please enter false. ");
      
      guess = input.nextBoolean();
      
    }
  
  loop = false;
  
    for (int i= 0; i < numberOfGuesses; ++i)
    {
    System.out.println ("Please enter your guess.");
   
    int guesses = input.nextInt();
    
        if (guesses > secretNumber)
        {
         System.out.println ("Your guess too high.");
        }
        
    if (guesses < secretNumber)
        {
         System.out.println ("Your guess too low.");
        }

       if (guesses == secretNumber) 
       { 
        System.out.println ("Congragulations you won the game.");
        
         loop = true;
        
        break;
       }
           
    }
    
    if (loop = false)
    
    System.out.println ("Sorry you lost the game.");
    
    System.out.println ("Would you like to see the secret number? If so please enter true, if not please enter false");
    
    seeSecretNumber = input.nextBoolean();
    
    if (seeSecretNumber == true)
    {
    System.out.println ("The secret number was "+ secretNumber);
    
   
   
   
   
  System.out.println ("Would you like to play again? If so please enter true, if not please enter false.");
    
    playAgain = input.nextBoolean();
    
    }
    
      
    }
    
    if (playAgain==false)
    {
        System.out.println ("Thank you for playing, have a good day and wash your hands!");
    }
    
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is an advice, you should break up your program methods. It makes life easier

Answer (score 0):

First, `if(loop = false)` should be `if(loop == false)`, you also forgot to add brackets{} after this if statement. Also your play statement is inside the seeSecretNumber if statement. I dont see a statement for `if(playAgain)` too. I would recommend re looking at the end of the program.